# Parsing part text with html in java

Tags: java, android, html, regex, parsing

I have one problem. At first I'm parsing some text from one site, I know that I can make parsing simple with element.text(), but I need make this text more beautiful. And I use elem.attr("class").equals("entry-content post_content") and then elem.toString(); and get object. Then I want to delete some text from this. For example:

```
<div class="entry-content post_content"> 
 <p><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia.png" rel="lightbox[24741]"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24748" alt="media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia" src="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia.png" width="680" height="470" /></a></p> 
<p>21-22 ноября в Санкт-Петербурге состоится пятый крупнейший медиа-форум в России &nbsp;&laquo;3D Журналистика&raquo;.<br /> В Арт-Пространстве “Freedom” соберутся главные редакторы крупнейших изданий, известные журналисты, владельцы медиа-холдингов и все те, кто делают журналистику “объемной”, чтобы рассказать участникам форума о главных трендах, актуальных проблемах и специфике работы в сфере журналистики.</p> 
<p><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FRC0UwhqGfs.jpg" rel="lightbox[24741]"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24752" alt="FRC0UwhqGfs" src="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/FRC0UwhqGfs.jpg" width="604" height="324" /></a><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/aijmiZXPjw4.jpg" rel="lightbox[24741]"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24749" alt="aijmiZXPjw4" src="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/aijmiZXPjw4.jpg" width="604" height="400" /></a></p> 
<p>Спикеры форума:</p> 
<p>- Главный редактор журнала “SNC” Анна Хрусталёва-Гехт.Тема выступления: “Ребрендинг глянцевого бренда на примере SNC: как за два года переубедить медиа-рынок”.</p> 
<p>- Главный редактор &laquo;Adme&raquo; Ксения Лукичева. Тема выступления: “Нормально делай, нормально будет. История AdMe”.</p> 
<p>- Главный редактор журнала &laquo;GEO&raquo; Владимир Есипов. Тема выступления: “Отличия и похожие черты travel-журналов и научно-популярных журналов”.</p>
```

And I need to replace this text:

```
<p><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia.png" rel="lightbox[24741]"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24748" alt="media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia" src="http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/media-forum-3d-zhurnalistika-informacionnaya-roskosh-clever-russia.png" width="680" height="470" /></a></p>
```

To this: ""
I try this way:

```
String regex = "<p><a>*</a></p>";
                    str = elem.toString();
                    str.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

But it doesn't work, please help me with this way or help me find new way

Comment: is your response format same for every time ? means first came <div then <p> with <a href.

Comment: yes, div is not needed because it's came only one time then <p><a href something in it </a></p> Then <p> Text which I need.</p> Then again <p><a href something in it </a></p>